# Is the change of policy of Imgur going to create problems for posts with images on SO?

Tags: discussion, imgur

I bumped into a Twitter message linking to a [policy change on Imgur](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/14415587638029/).

I don't know if nudity images are used anywhere on SO, but the "old, unused, and inactive content that is not tied to a user account from our platform" part seems pretty dangerous if images used in SO questions and answers are supposed to be archived safely.

There is going to be any impact on SO for this change of policy?

Comment: See also the [corresponding post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/335251).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope.

SE runs [a corporate version](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/) of Imgur, so image persistence is guaranteed.

I also see no valid reason for nudity on SO, so that seems extremely unlikely to have any (negative) effect.

Comment: We do have [naked-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naked-objects). Didn't have time to check for images ...yet ...

Comment: Also [tag:nude.js]

Comment: @SurajRao I actually found it under [tag:nude.js], right on the first page: [nudes on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15870703/7395227)

Comment: Well, nudity might be valid in sites like Biology where they need to show something related to the private parts. :)

Comment: He's asking about SO, though, @Shadow :D

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, I'm too used to MSE probably. (someone in my chat posted link to this question. ;))

Comment: Naked pointers, too. But C++ tends to call them "raw" these days.

Comment: See also [the Terms of Service's Acceptable Use Policy section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), which states: "_Sexually Explicit Material. Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended._"

Comment: But it wasn't always that way, was it?  Early SE had people using imgur.com anonymously and posting links to it.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Exposing private parts to the caller is frowned upon on SO. Private encapsulation is widely recognized as the appropriate way to go. Exposing members in `public` is inappropriate! Programmers are very sensitive about these things and anyone who posts pictures of such (instead of text) will very likely get down-voted.

Comment: @Lundin and rightly so! :D

Answer (score 20):

#### While it does not affect all images on Stack Overflow, there are a lot of images on Stack Overflow hosted on Imgur outside of the dedicated Stack Exchange hosting

- `url:"/imgur.com"` - [24,287 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fimgur.com%22) (not SE hosting)
- `url:"/i.imgur.com"` - [52,049 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fi.imgur.com%22) (not SE hosting)
- `url:"/i.stack.imgur.com"` - [3,012,515 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%22) (SE hosting)

Assuming one image per post and no overlap between posts linking to imgur.com and i.imgur.com, 24287 + 52049 = **76336 images on Stack Overflow could be affected**, which is 76336/(76336 + 3012515) = 0.0247, or **just under 2.5%** of Imgur-hosted images linked from Stack Overflow.

We can't know how many of those images *are* affected, though, as we don't have any way of knowing whether they were uploaded by logged-in users or not.

Comment: Note that "/imgur.com" links could be albums/galleries too, which usually include multiple images.

Comment: However, such content is likely not useful in the first place. People going out of their way to use an external image host are probably not very interested in reading and following posting guidelines - especially the one about how to post code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel There are definitely legitimate reasons to do it, including more generous filesize limits, especially with animated images.  And there are certainly plenty of examples of useful content that would be harmed, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698).

Comment: I guess SE could automatically re-upload them under their imgur account, if they wanted to? Or would there be some legal problem (license of external linked content) maybe?

Comment: The TOS change of imgur happened already and clicking on the search links gives even slightly higher results. It seems that no deletion yet has happened.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [RyanM's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424279/is-the-change-of-policy-of-imgur-going-to-create-problems-for-all-posts-with-ima/424379#424379) for the correct calculation.

**Yes.**

According to the answer on [the corresponding MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388559/284601), we can do a search with the following terms to get an idea of how many posts have images via the corporate version of Imgur (*i.imgur*) vs. the non-corporate version (*imgur*):

`url:https://imgur.com` - 17,651 results

`url:https://i.imgur.com` - 42,785 results

Assuming, worst-case, that all of the **non-corporate Imgur uploads** were done anonymously, about **30% will break** (assuming one image per search result).

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was worrying about short term. I've occasionally observed images in my very old posts breaking in the past but never investigated about what happened. What scares me a bit more is that such a change in policy means something serious is happening... what if imgur just goes belly up in a few months? What would be the effect on SO? ... does it really matter SO uses a corporate account if the account is in a service from a company that doesn't exist any more?

Comment: @6502 of course Imgur will not publicly state that they are in any kind of trouble, however from the announcement it does seem that this change is purely about content curation and removing unwanted images, there is nothing that hints at problems with the business model. And even if that were the case then they would probably stop free hosting for individual users and continue as a paid service, which means that SO as a paying customer can still use the platform.

Comment: @Marijn: they're not changing rules from now on (i.e. blocking uploads). They're not removing them from searches. They're breaching hosting promises. Saying they're breaching contracts in a part that is not important for SO is only partially reassuring. Difficult to believe for me there's no very hard problematic reason (money comes to mind) behind such a bold move. I'd be curious to know how much of imgur data and bandwidth is NSFW, but it's probably not trivial to find out (especially bandwidth... I just made a quick random sample and out of 100 only 4 were unquestionably NSFW)

Comment: **citation needed for your "30%"**. [There are 5,214,670 in the stackexchange network using the corporate imgur](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ai.stack.imgur.com) right now, so even if you assume that **every** image on the non-corporate imgur gets taken down, that's still only 1.15%. How exactly are you getting that number?

Comment: @user The post you are commenting on explains exactly where that number comes from, and links to the source of the data used. It looks like your criticism is that the search should be for `i.stack.imgur.com`, not `i.imgur.com`.

Comment: @user You asked for a citation, and you asked where the number came from. The post you are commenting on already gives a link and says how they got that number. I do not see any unattributed numbers in this post. There is no claim lacking a citation, except perhaps the claim that `i.imgur.com` is the URL for the corporate version of Imgur (which it apparently isn't, according to your linked post).

Comment: @user The post they linked to is the source for the numbers 17,651 and 42,785. From those numbers we get 30%, if (as this post claims) the 17,651 number is for the non-corporate Imgur and the 42,785 number is for the corporate Imgur.

Comment: @user As I said, you asked for a citation but no citation is missing. The problem is that they used the numbers incorrectly, not that they used numbers without saying where those numbers came from. I don't know why you think I haven't read your MSE post, when my comment here that you are apparently angry enough about to respond in ALL CAPS already stated: *"it apparently isn't, according to your linked post"*.

Comment: @kaya3 ok. what I really meant by that was "explanation needed".

Comment: [I re-did the numbers, but correctly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424379/208273).

Comment: The wording for that 30% was confusing, and implied it was talking about __all__ imgur images on SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus it's not confusing. it's just wrong :P